# Why I cannot make a bold text on my wall?

Tags: facebook

I am trying to post some bold text to Facebook (it's part of the app I am making). I read in numerous articles on the net that I can easily make a bold text by surrounding it with * symbols.

However, I make a sample text like `make me *bold*`, and it does not appear bold.

When I post bold text make via some online tools, it does appear bold.

What's the catch? How can I make bold/italic text work when posting something to my wall?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No catch, you simply cannot do this. Bold accents only for Google+.

Comment: So why so many article on the net about it?! Also, If I post bolded text, it will remain bold. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can't whilst posting on your wall. To make something bold ("**") and to underline something ("_ _") are only for the chat.